# Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got error

> Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\FaridWeb\latihan4\index.php on line 6

```
<button><a href="form_input.php">Tambah Daftar</a></button>
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mhs";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo "<table border=1 style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
        <tr><th>NIM</th><th>Nama Mahasiswa</th><th>Tanggal Lahir</th></tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>$row[nim]</td><td>$row[nama]</td><td>$row[tgl_lahir]</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` say if you put it before the `if`?

Comment: @Al.G. bool(false)

Comment: Then the query failed for some reason. Check for it this way: `if(!$result) { die($conn->error); }`.

Comment: @Al.G. It's always better to recommend switching error reporting instead.

Comment: @Dharman I intended this a quick way to locate the problem. I agree with you though.